# Clicking on Angular UI Bootstrap Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the radio buttons implemented in UI Bootstrap firing a function by including a ng-click on the button. Apparently the radio button variable updates after the function has been called. I've created a Plunker to show this behaviour and explain the problem where the function fires an alert with the content of the variable.

[Radio Buttons Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TEqK5VnixhM29GMAm2EK?p=info)

Is there a simple way of solving this issue. Maybe by making the function to wait for the variable to update...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, simple fix. Use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` on your radio buttons.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/0Jf4qrpHAXY8MeeVA3kl?p=preview